# How to fetch value from Mysql table using multiple condition with optional value

Tags: php, mysql

I need to retrieve all data from MYSQL table with multiple condition but some inputs are optional here. I am explaining my table below.

> db_exam:

```
id   name   reg_no     zone    center    college    sub_code  

1    aaa      12         3       AB        scs          2

2    bbb      12         2       AB        BJB           2

3    ccc      13         3       AB        BJB          3
```

I am passing the below input to fetch the all data.

```
reg_no=12
zone=3
center=AB
sub_code=2
```

From the above input some are optional means the value of column `center and sub_code` may be there or may be blank. Here I need query to fetch all the data using the above conditions and the value of column `center=AB or center=''` and `sub_code=2 or sub_code=''` . But first 2 condition are mandatory.

Comment: Use inner and outer joins, these allow you to conditionally select data only when both sides match.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
select * from db_exam where reg_no=12 and zone=3 and (center=AB or center='') and (sub_code=2 or sub_code='')
```

Comment: That won't do it...the query will only return something when everything matches....you need to use joins left and right to select parts when matches are valid.

Comment: you directly putting the input value which may not right.

Answer (score 0):

User **Where IN** Query like below.
**Pass input value and default value like empty string ''.**

```
SELECT * 
FROM db_exam
WHERE (reg_no = <number> AND zone= <number> AND center IN (<input>, '') AND sub_code IN (<input>, ''));
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT
        t1.id
       ,t1.name
       ,t1.reg_no
       ,t1.zone
       ,t1.college
       ,t2.center
       ,t3.sub_code
    FROM db_exam t1
    INNER JOIN db_exam t2
    ON t2.id=t1.id
    AND t2.center='AB'
    INNER JOIN db_exam t3
    ON t3.id=t1.id
    AND t3.sub_code=2;
```